# Proving the equivalence between two definitions of Reiman integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am looking for a proof of the equivalence between two different definitions of Riemann integral, this first one comes from *Understanding Analysis* by Abbot.

> $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ if and only if for each $\epsilon >0$ there exist a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that for any refinement $P$ of $P_\epsilon$ $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$$ and the integral is then $$\int_a^b f := \overline{\int_a^b} f=\underline{\int_a^b}f$$

where $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$ are respectively the upper and lower Riemann sums, and $\overline{\int_a^b} f,\underline{\int_a^b}f$ are respectively the upper and lower integral.

---

The other very useful definition is:

> $\displaystyle \int_a^b f =\lim_{||P||\to0} \sum(f,P^*)$ if the limit exists. That is
>   $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists\delta>0: \forall P^* ,||P||<\delta \Longrightarrow \left|\displaystyle \int_a^b f-\sum(f,P^*)\right|<\epsilon$

Where

$P=\{a=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=b\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$

$P^*=(P,\xi)$ , $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots,\xi_n)$ , $t_{i-1}\le\xi_i \le t_i$

and $\displaystyle \sum (f,P^*)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(\xi_i) \cdot (t_i-t_{i-1}) $

$||P||=\underset {1\le i\le n}{\text{max}} (t_i-t_{i-1})$.

Obviously even a link to a proof is very welcome by me, I searched around but I could not find a post where this exact equivalence was discussed.

Comment: you should start with  simple cases : for example $f$ piecewise constant, or with $|f'(x)| < C$ on $[a,b]$, for example $f$ a polynomial, and finish the proof with $f$ piecewise uniformly  continuous on $[a,b]$

Comment: Why would piecewise uniformly continuous finish it?

Comment: Some books refer to this equivalence as Darboux Theorem http://www.terpconnect.umd.edu/~lvrmr/2006-2007-F/Classes/MATH410/Riemann.pdf